# can't see describe queries in zend framework db profiler

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, describe

I have zend database profiler set up and turned on in my development site. I can see all the queries except for the DESCRIBE queries, which I know it should be running each time I ask for a new table object. I'm using something like this to look at the queries:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$profiler = new Zend_Db_Profiler();
$profiler->setEnabled(true);
$db->setProfiler($profiler);

$i = 1;
$output = 'PROFILE FOR: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\n";

    foreach ($profiler->getQueryProfiles() as $query) {
        $output .= "Query ".$i++.": ".$query->getQuery(). "\n";
    }
    $output .= 'Average query length: ' . $totalTime / $queryCount .
                ' seconds' . "\n";

    $output .= 'Queries per second: ' . $queryCount / $totalTime . "\n";
    $output .= 'Longest query length: ' . $longestTime . "\n";
    $output .= "Longest query: \n" . $longestQuery . "\n\n";

    file_put_contents('/tmp/zend_profiler.log', $output, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Not sure why I can't see the describe queries. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have activated the metadata cache for you database connection (which usually is a very good thing especially in production). In that case the `DESCRIBE` queries won't be executed until the cache expires.

Verify it by executing this line somewhere in application after the bootstrap

```
if (null != Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultMetadataCache()) {
  echo "Cache is active, describe queries not run";
} else {
  echo "Cache is not active";
}
```